# Sequelize associated model can be reached only when calling Model.findOne() method, but not when calling Model.create()

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Here is what I do:

```
const blablabla = async (currentUser) => {    
let createdRoom = await Room.create({ include: [{ model: User }] });
        console.log('outside')
        console.log(createdRoom)
        Room.findOne({where:{id:createdRoom.id}, include: [{model: User}]})
            .then(room => {
                console.log('inside')
                console.log(room);
                room.users.push(currentUser); 

            })
}
```

When I try to reach `createdRoom.users` there's somehow `undefined`, but in `foundRoom` `users` array is available. Why there's no `users` in `createdRoom`?

Output from `console.log(createdRoom)`

```
room {
  dataValues: {
    id: '1b44d10c-42c2-4720-9e90-85157ab65b25',
    updatedAt: 2020-04-03T18:30:48.442Z,
    createdAt: 2020-04-03T18:30:48.442Z
  },
```

Output from `console.log(foundRoom)`

```
room {
  dataValues: {
    id: '1b44d10c-42c2-4720-9e90-85157ab65b25',
    createdAt: 2020-04-03T18:30:48.442Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-04-03T18:30:48.442Z,
    users: []
  },
```

Comment: let createdRoom = await Room.create({ include: [{ model: User }] }), this seems wrong, you're passing the User model to include, not a model instance. In the sequelize docs, it says this about the options.include for Create(): "An array of include options - Used to build prefetched/included model instances. See set". Take a look here: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-create

Comment: seems like this is why I'm not getting users after creatio, thank you!